# RSpec helper method doesn't change default argument value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm having a realy strange situation here.

I created a helper to perform a 'log in' in my integration tests with RSpec/Capybara:

```
module AuthenticationHelper
  def log_in(user = User.new, remember_me = false)
    visit new_user_session_path

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    check("user_remember_me") if remember_me
    save_screenshot("/vagrant/screenshot.png")
    click_button "Log in"
  end
end
```

As you can see, it has the `remember_me` argument, with default value `false`. It works fine in some kind of tests:

```
  context "when 'remember-me' isn't checked" do
    before do
      log_in create(:user)
      reset_session!
      visit root_path
    end

    it "should not stay connected when browser close the session" do
      expect(page).to have_selector("a[href='#{destroy_user_session_path}']", count: 0)
    end
  end
```

However, when I need to change the `remember_me` default value calling `log_in` method, its value simply doesn't change:

```
  context "when 'remember-me' is checked" do
    before do
      log_in(create(:user), true)
      reset_session!
      visit root_path
    end

    it "should stay connected when browser close the session" do
      expect(page).to have_selector("a[href='#{destroy_user_session_path}']", count: 1)
    end
  end
```

Here is how I configured it in my `rails_helper.rb`:

```
.
.
.
require 'helpers/authentication_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|

config.include AuthenticationHelper, type: :feature
.
.
.
```

I already tested fixing `remember_me` with `true` just to confirm that the method call is the problem.

What I let pass that is causing this behavior?

Comment: Where does the `reset_session!` method come from?  I couldn't find it in the Capybara API, so is it a custom method?  Does it destroy all your permanent cookies as well as your `session` cookies?  If you mean `reset_sessions!`, then it looks like that method destroys all your cookies, and you may want to use something like [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) to test this functionality.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti, ``reset_session!`` belongs to Capybara and is a alias from ``reset!``. You can find it [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Areset!).

Comment: Thanks, so it is!  I assume then that method is just blowing away _all_ your cookies (since it "remove[s] cookies and navigate[s] to blank page"), rather than expiring the permanent ones.  I still think you might want to take a look at `show_me_the_cookies`.

Comment: You were right, @PaulFioravanti. ``show_me_the_cookies`` solved my problem. Thanks! The orginal problem ("doesn't change default argument value") was weird to me, and now I see that was wrong: the value changes, and I was mistaken with the result of the other debugging tests who also where calling the helper method, and at this time without ``true`` value in ``remember_me`` argument. For this naive error in the question description, I apologize.

Comment: Great!  I'll put that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing "remember me" functionality would require the ability to expire a permanent cookie without deleting it (I think that [`Capybara::Session#reset_session!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session#reset%21-instance_method) is deleting *all* your cookies), and that is a use case that the [`show_me_the_cookies` gem](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) does really well.